# How to show database value in spinner in android

Tags: java, android

In my page, I have two spinner i want to show value from SQLite database. I can easily show a value in edit text. But i dont know how to show in spinner.

I tried like this:

```
String addr_country = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ADDRESS_COLUMN_COUNTRY));

country.setText((CharSequence) addr_country);
```

But its not working.. How to do

Comment: use an adapter, `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way:

```
String[] list = //get data from your database
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

`dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`

```
spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: How to get data from database and store in array string

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667408/get-data-from-database-android)